# Change MVC Routes

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I have hosted a ASP.NET MVC website on IIS 7.5. The problem is that the site name and controller name are same, due to this I have to enter the controller name twice.

I am not allowed to change the name of the site or controller. My current URL for eg.

```
local/home/home/action
```

but I have shared as

```
localhost/home/action
```

now I need to configure the application so that the application routes properly for

```
localhost/home/action
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a new route to RouteConfig.cs before others routes like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "DefaultHome",
    url: "{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MVC5 you can use the `Route` attribute. Like so:

```
[Route(“yourroot”)]
public ActionResult Index() { … }
```

More information can be found here [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET MVC 5](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)

Hope this helps